# Spring Batch limits number of concurrent threads to 10

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-batch

I've got Spring Boot application with Spring Batch framework. My goal is simple - run certain job concurrently. I want to be able to, let's say, run 15 threads in the same time and reject every excessive one. Here's my configuration class:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.JobRegistry;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class GeneratingReportJobConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private GeneratingReportTask task;

    @Autowired
    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor(JobRegistry jobRegistry) {
        JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
        jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        return jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(15);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(15);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(0);
        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher(TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("generatingReportJob")
                .start(step())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("generatingReportTask")
                .tasklet(task)
                .build();
    }
}
```

The thing is, whatever I'm trying to do - application runs at most 10 jobs at the same time. I've tried experimenting with `TaskExecutor` - my first logical choice was `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`, which appeared to stash 
every excessive request and then run them in a random order which is not intended.

So later I've tried to manipulate that limit and, as you can see in the code, I've started using `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`, which allowed me to set the limit to 5, for example, and it worked as expected - at most 5 threads could run at the same time and next ones were being rejected while these 5 were running. However, setting the limit to 15 resulted in behaviour similar to the previous one. Still, 11th request was being queued, whereas 16th was being rejected. This is almost my intended behaviour, however I need to be able to fully control thread execution.

Jobs are being invoked via `@RestController` using `jobLauncher.run()`. Every excessive request results in browser loading until being able to start execution. Seems like, program is being frozen somewhere inside `jobLauncher.run()` (when able to start job execution it just exits - that's how async run works).

Comment: I'm studiying a little bit the argument cause is interesting :) when you say: "setting the limit to 15 resulted in behaviour similar to the previous " do you mean the core or max pool size?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your configuration. You should be able to run more than 10 jobs concurrently (up to 15 according to your example). Probably your job is consuming a lot of resources and you have a hardware limit? (ie your JVM is not able to spawn more than 10 threads?).

Comment: @rick both of them. you can see this in my code preview under `taskExecutor()` method

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine well, job is just `Thread.sleep()` for 30 seconds, so I suppose it can't be the matter

Comment: I tried that as well and I'm able to run up to 15 jobs concurrently: https://gist.github.com/benas/fb729bd25c75667c8dc24c9c4d9d6b1d. In that case, I'm not sure why you are limited to 10..

Comment: Do you have an example on Git so I can pull and take look the issue?

Comment: @dominikbrandon I faced similar issue and solved by setting throttle limit as core pool size

Answer (score 2):

Bit late but try to check if you are using HikariCP which has a default 10 simultaneous DB connexions limit

Just faced similar issue and resolved by increasing `spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size`

See: [Number of parallel threads processing is capped to 10 with Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68267922/number-of-parallel-threads-processing-is-capped-to-10-with-spring-batch)

Comment: You may be right, but I can't verify if this works anymore. Anyway, thanks for your answer.